# How to track most used filters on product filter page with GTM and GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a custom build page where users can filter products based on price, category, brand, ...
These are made out of checkboxes and a range input for the price.
I'm trying to figure out what the best way would be to track every action/filter in order to find out which brand / categories are the most popular.

***Important to know***
The menu contains a submenu for the categories. When the user clicks one of these links the filterpage will have this category checked in the filters.
The page does not reload when applying a filter. I'm using JS to perform a search and show new results. The page url gets updated with the correct search query parameters.

I think I have 2 options:

1. Track click events on the checkboxes and send every change with datalayer.push.
2. Track the page URL after each filter.

Option 1 is an issue because people might go to the page with some parameters in the URL. This won't be tracked because there was no click event. This issue will also apply to users that click the category in the submenu that prefills the filter.

Option 2 also is an issue because with this solution the category might be tracked 5 times if the user keeps adding or removing other filters. It always tracks all filters instead of the one that has been added.

Answer (score 1):

The first step of tracking is using the analog of Occam's Razor. You want to cut off stuff that has no chance of answering legit business questions.

Your business question here is: `What filters are the most helpful for the users?` Now it's important to know why the business wants to know it. Cuz remember, the business is not very competent at data analysis even if it doesn't realize it.

So you need to know exactly how answering that question improves OKRs/KPIs. In this case, the legit answer could be: `cuz we want to sort the filters by the usage frequency and measure if that would ease the engagement and thus, improve the conversion rate for the part of the journey from the product list to the pdp`

That's a pretty weak reason, but passable. Especially if there's an issue in that transition currently.

Good, now having that context, why would we want to track filters used in pre-populated urls? Say some overzealous employee made a mistake and pre-populated some weird unneeded filter using, say, date and time of when the product has been added. And now they use that URL in all ads, so you get a lot of third party traffic coming to product lists with a date as a filter.

And then, let's say, that employee keeps using that filter for other persistent links to the effect of the date/time filter becoming uncanningly popular. There. Your data slowly becomes garbage and stops answering the original question.

There are other issues with tracking pre-set filters, some of which you've outlined, but the real issue is the ability of the data to answer good business questions clearly. Tracking all filters may be able to answer some technical questions, but it's not the aim of behavioral analytics to answer technical questions. Let them use access logs and whatever else they use to answer those.

Comment: You sure do make so good points. I actually want to know which brands or types visitors are mostly interested in. With the information we can do some promotions on the popular brands/types. What I understand from your explanation is that we should not track this kind of stuff with GA.

Comment: For product brands and types you likely don't even want to analyze PLP, you mostly just analyze PDP pageviews that should include brand and type in them. Or use purchase data. For either, you can use both front-end or back-end data, but back-end will be a lot more accurate. No ad-blockers affect backend.